# Removing a personalized class inside the view.py - Django

Tags: python, django, openpyxl

here is my view.py. Despite the code is a little bit long, I'd like to remove the `class Ibm()` from inside the `else` element to a new file called `Ibm_class.py`. I tried to do that but I couldn't find any way!

```
def index(request):
if 'GET' == request.method:
    return render(request, 'auditoria_app/index.html')
else:
    class Ibm(object):
        def __init__(self, i):
            self.numeroIbm = inputsCombo[get_column_letter(i) + str(10)].value
            self.nome = inputsCombo[get_column_letter(i) + str(11)].value
            self.cidade = inputsCombo[get_column_letter(i) + str(12)].value
            self.uf = inputsCombo[get_column_letter(i) + str(13)].value
            self.anosProjeto = inputsCombo[get_column_letter(i) + str(16)].value
            self.anosAlternativa = inputsDNCombo[get_column_letter(i) + str(14)].value
            if self.anosAlternativa is None:
                self.anosAlternativa = 0
            self.tipoInvestimento = inputsCombo[get_column_letter(i) + str(21)].value
            self.tipoProposta = inputsCombo[get_column_letter(i) + str(24)].value
            self.inicioVigencia = inputsCombo[get_column_letter(i) + str(34)].value
            self.prazoContrato = inputsCombo[get_column_letter(i) + str(38)].value

            # gas station variables
            self.faixaMargem = inputsCombo[get_column_letter(i) + str(19)].value
            self.rebateTotalCI = 0
            self.rebateTotalCB = 0
            self.unitariaCI = 0
            self.volumeMensalCI = inputsCombo[get_column_letter(i) + str(60)].value
            self.volumeMensalCB = inputsDNCombo[get_column_letter(i) + str(32)].value
            self.margemCurva = inputsCombo[get_column_letter(i) + str(67)].value * 1000
            self.margemCI = []
            self.margemCB = []
            self.volume12m = 0
            self.margem12m = 0
            self.curvaPostoCI = []
            self.curvaPostoCB = []
            self.rebateCI = []
            self.rebateCB = []
            self.faixaReal = ''
            self.volumeTotalCI = inputsCombo[get_column_letter(i) + str(151)].value
            self.volumeTotalCB = inputsDNCombo[get_column_letter(i) + str(121)].value

            # SELECT store variables
            self.feeIsencao = inputsCombo[get_column_letter(i) + str(220)].value
            self.feeFaturamento = inputsCombo[get_column_letter(i) + str(222)].value
            self.feeReal = inputsCombo[get_column_letter(i) + str(224)].value
            self.faturamento = inputsCombo[get_column_letter(i) + str(173)].value
            self.pvl = inputsCombo[get_column_letter(i) + str(184)].value
            self.feeLoja = inputsCombo[get_column_letter(i) + str(174)].value
            self.cashback = []

            # credit variables
            self.prazoMogasCI1 = inputsCombo[get_column_letter(i) + str(159)].value
            self.prazoMogasCI2 = inputsCombo[get_column_letter(i) + str(160)].value
            self.prazoMogasCI3 = inputsCombo[get_column_letter(i) + str(161)].value
            self.prazoMogasCB1 = inputsDNCombo[get_column_letter(i) + str(151)].value
            self.prazoMogasCB2 = inputsDNCombo[get_column_letter(i) + str(152)].value
            self.prazoMogasCB3 = inputsDNCombo[get_column_letter(i) + str(153)].value

            # economics IBM
            self.unitariaIBM = arredonda(outputCombo[get_column_letter(i - 1) + str(42)].value)
            self.hsIBM = arredonda(outputCombo[get_column_letter(i - 1) + str(36)].value)
            self.cmIBM = percentual(outputCombo[get_column_letter(i - 1) + str(39)].value)
            self.tirIBM = percentual(outputCombo[get_column_letter(i - 1) + str(54)].value)
            self.npvIBM = arredonda(outputCombo[get_column_letter(i - 1) + str(55)].value)

            # if self.tipoInvestimento != 'Loja':
            for k in range(0, self.anosProjeto):
                margemCI = inputsCombo[get_column_letter(i) + str(109 + k)].value
                if margemCI is None or margemCI == '':
                    margemCI = 0
                self.margemCI.append(arredonda(margemCI * 1000))

                curvaPostoCI = inputsCombo[get_column_letter(i) + str(130 + k)].value
                if curvaPostoCI is None or 0:
                    curvaPostoCI = 1
                self.curvaPostoCI.append(arredonda(curvaPostoCI * 100))

                rebateCI = inputsCombo[get_column_letter(i) + str(305 + k)].value
                if rebateCI is None:
                    rebateCI = 0
                self.rebateCI.append(rebateCI * 1000)

                cashback = inputsCombo[get_column_letter(i) + str(485 + k)].value
                if cashback is None:
                    cashback = 0
                else:
                    cashback = cashback / self.faturamento
                self.cashback.append(cashback)

            for y in range(0, self.anosAlternativa):
                margemCB = inputsDNCombo[get_column_letter(i) + str(79 + y)].value
                if margemCB is None or margemCB == '':
                    margemCB = 0
                self.margemCB.append(arredonda(margemCB * 1000))

                curvaPostoCB = inputsDNCombo[get_column_letter(i) + str(100 + y)].value
                if curvaPostoCB is None or 0:
                    curvaPostoCB = 1
                self.curvaPostoCB.append(arredonda(curvaPostoCB * 100))

                rebateCB = inputsDNCombo[get_column_letter(i) + str(204 + y)].value
                if rebateCB is None:
                    rebateCB = 0
                self.rebateCB.append(rebateCB * 1000)

            # Selecionando os dados da Loja Select
            # if self.tipoInvestimento == 'Loja':

            self.curvaLojaCI = []
            self.curvaLojaCB = []

            for k in range(0, self.anosProjeto):
                curvaLojaCI = inputsCombo[get_column_letter(i) + str(198 + k)].value
                if curvaLojaCI is None or 0:
                    curvaLojaCI = 1
                self.curvaLojaCI.append(curvaLojaCI)

            for k in range(0, self.anosAlternativa):
                curvaLojaCB = inputsDNCombo[get_column_letter(i) + str(123 + k)].value
                if curvaLojaCB is None or 0:
                    curvaLojaCB = 1
                self.curvaLojaCB.append(curvaLojaCB)

            self.fpCI = inputsCombo[get_column_letter(i) + str(283)].value
            if self.fpCI is None:
                self.fpCI = 0
            self.rviCI = inputsCombo[get_column_letter(i) + str(285)].value
            if self.rviCI is None:
                self.rviCI = 0

            self.fpCB = inputsDNCombo[get_column_letter(i) + str(201)].value
            if self.fpCB is None:
                self.fpCB = 0
            self.rviCB = inputsDNCombo[get_column_letter(i) + str(202)].value
            if self.rviCB is None:
                self.rviCB = 0

            # initializing gas station functions
            self.get_volume()
            self.rebate_total_CI()
            self.rebate_total_CB()
            # self.unitaria_CI()
            self.check_faixa()

        def get_volume(self):
            if self.tipoInvestimento != 'Loja':
                for j in range(2, sigma.max_row + 1):
                    if self.numeroIbm == sigma['A' + str(j)].value:
                        self.margem12m = sigma['D' + str(j)].value
                        self.volume12m = sigma['E' + str(j)].value

        def check_faixa(self):
            if self.tipoInvestimento != 'Loja':
                if self.faixaMargem[0] == 'R':
                    pass
                else:
                    for row in range(5, faixas.max_row + 1):
                        cidade = faixas['C' + str(row)].value
                        if cidade == unidecode.unidecode(self.cidade.upper() + '/' + self.uf.upper()):
                            self.faixaReal = faixas['D' + str(row)].value
                    if self.faixaReal == '':
                        self.faixaReal = 'n/a'

        def rebate_total_CI(self):
            if self.tipoInvestimento != 'Loja':
                rebateTotalCI = 0
                for k in range(0, self.anosProjeto):
                    rebateTotalCI += self.volumeMensalCI * 12 * self.curvaPostoCI[k] * self.rebateCI[k]
                self.rebateTotalCI = arredonda(rebateTotalCI / 1000)

        def rebate_total_CB(self):
            if self.tipoInvestimento != 'Loja':
                rebateTotalCB = 0
                for k in range(0, self.anosAlternativa):
                    rebateTotalCB += self.volumeMensalCB * 12 * self.curvaPostoCB[k] * self.rebateCB[k]
                self.rebateTotalCB = arredonda(rebateTotalCB / 1000)

        # UNIT might be extracted from 'OutPut COMBO'
        # def unitaria_CI(self):
        #     self.unitariaCI = (self.rebateTotalCI + self.fpCI + self.rviCI)*10/self.volumeTotalCI

        def check_volume_mensal(self):
            return self.volumeMensalCI - self.volumeMensalCB

        def check_volume_total(self):
            return self.volumeTotalCI - self.volumeTotalCB

        def check_volumeCB_SIC(self):
            return self.volumeMensalCB

    excel_file = request.FILES["excel_file"]
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_file, data_only=True)
    inputsCombo = wb['Inputs COMBO']
    inputsDNCombo = wb['Inputs DN COMBO']
    outputCombo = wb['OutPut COMBO']
    faixas = wb['Faixas']

    wb2 = openpyxl.load_workbook('media/sigma.xlsx', data_only=True)
    sigma = wb2['Planilha1']

    wb3 = openpyxl.load_workbook('media/performance.xlsx', data_only=True)
    sic = wb3['Performance']

    wb4 = openpyxl.load_workbook('media/ultimoContrato.xlsm', data_only=True)
    ultimoContrato = wb4['Base']

    numeroIbms = inputsCombo['F5'].value
    ibms = []

    for i in range(8, 8 + numeroIbms):
        ibm = Ibm(i)
        ibms.append(ibm)

    return render(request, 'auditoria_app/index.html', {'ibms': ibms})
```

-> wb: file is loaded from a upload

-> wb2, wb3, wb4: files are stored inside the media folder

I tried to copy/paste this class and then import it to the `view.py` file but the `excel_file` variable must be inside the `view` and is still needed inside the `Ibm_class.py`. Any suggestion, pls?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "_couldn't find any way!_"? You mean you can't copy-paste that code to another file and then just import the file? What error are you experiencing?

Comment: I tried to copy/paste this class and then import it to the view.py file but the excel_file variable must be inside the view and is still needed inside the 'Ibm_class.py'. Any suggestion, pls?

Comment: There you go. That is the issue that you must include in the description. Update the question with that.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback... I've just updated... any help?

Comment: You'll need to show some more code/detail and probably the full error (stacktrace) that you're seeing, because `excel_file` isn't used in the `Ibm` class, it's only defined and used in `def index()` for `POST` requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) on your class instead of relying on local/global scope variables. Here, instead of directly using `inputsCombo`, `inputsDNCombo`, `outputCombo`, `faixas`, and `sigma` variables within your class, just pass them to the `Ibm` constructor as class attributes.

**views.py**

```
...
from my_app.ibm import Ibm  # Or wherever you would put that class
...

def index(request):
    ...
    else:
        excel_file = request.FILES["excel_file"]
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_file, data_only=True)
        inputsCombo = wb['Inputs COMBO']
        inputsDNCombo = wb['Inputs DN COMBO']
        outputCombo = wb['OutPut COMBO']
        faixas = wb['Faixas']

        wb2 = openpyxl.load_workbook('media/sigma.xlsx', data_only=True)
        sigma = wb2['Planilha1']

        ...

        for i in range(8, 8 + numeroIbms):
            # Pass the dependencies to the constructor of Ibm class
            ibm = Ibm(i, inputsCombo, inputsDNCombo, outputCombo, faixas, sigma)
            ...

        ...
```

**ibm.py**

```
class Ibm(object):
    # Accept the injected parameters to Ibm class
    def __init__(self, i, inputsCombo, inputsDNCombo, outputCombo, faixas, sigma):
        self.numeroIbm = inputsCombo[get_column_letter(i) + str(10)].value
        self.anosAlternativa = inputsDNCombo[get_column_letter(i) + str(14)].value
        self.unitariaIBM = arredonda(outputCombo[get_column_letter(i - 1) + str(42)].value)

        # For the arguments that will be used by your other functions e.g. check_faixa, define them as class attributes here
        self.faixas = faixas
        self.sigma = sigma

    def get_volume(self):
        if self.tipoInvestimento != 'Loja':
            for j in range(2, self.sigma.max_row + 1):  # Append "self." to the usage of "sigma" to refer to the class attribute that was set in __init__
                if self.numeroIbm == self.sigma['A' + str(j)].value:
                    self.margem12m = self.sigma['D' + str(j)].value
                    self.volume12m = self.sigma['E' + str(j)].value

    def check_faixa(self):
        if self.tipoInvestimento != 'Loja':
            if self.faixaMargem[0] == 'R':
                pass
            else:
                for row in range(5, self.faixas.max_row + 1):    # Append "self." to the usage of "faixas" to refer to the class attribute that was set in __init__
                    cidade = self.faixas['C' + str(row)].value
                    if cidade == unidecode.unidecode(self.cidade.upper() + '/' + self.uf.upper()):
                        self.faixaReal = self.faixas['D' + str(row)].value
                if self.faixaReal == '':
                    self.faixaReal = 'n/a'
```